# После скачивания jQuery не открывается на Windows 10

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, почему в Win 10 не открывается скачанная программа jQuery 3.1.0 min и всплывает окно с сообщением "  'n' is null or not an object" , source : Microsoft JScript runtime error?

Comment: как идет попытка открыть?

Comment: Нужно было Linux ставить

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию, в системах Windows, для открытия файлов с расширением `.js` установлено приложение Windows Based Script Host

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому при попытке открыть/запустить файл, наверняка будут ошибки исполнения, так как могут использоваться объекты специфичные для браузера или другой среды выполнения, типа nodejs, и отсутствующие в текущей среде выполнения.

В качестве решения можно просто заменить приложение по умолчанию на текстовый редактор, либо открывать файлы данного типа с помощью текстовых редакторов.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery не программа, а библиотека JavaScript, фокусирующаяся на взаимодействии JavaScript и HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. jquery не программа, а библиотека для языка джаваскрипт. если вы скачали ее правильно то у нее должно быть расширение js. данная библиотека работает при включениии ее в хтмл вашей страницы  тегами 
        "<"script src="путь к вашей библиотеки Js"">""<"/script">"

Comment: по умолчанию расширения скрыты. поэтому вполне возможно автор видит название _jQuery 3.1.0 min_

Answer (score 0):

Для начала советую прочитать [Что такое Html](http://www.site-do.ru/html/) далее [Что такое JS](http://www.site-do.ru/js/js.php). В принципе я думаю для ответа на этот вопрос и очень общего понимания будет достаточно этого сайта.